# How to extract schema from XML variable using XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd, xquery

Technologies: T-SQL, XML, XQuery

I have an XML @variable in a database table which has a schema section and data section. I would only like to extra only the schema section and create a XML Schema Collection for it. It appears XQuery would be the quickest way. How do I specify the starting tag and ending tag in the following file (I only want to extract everything between `<xs:schema xmlns` and `</xs:schema>`?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [etl].[ufn_GetXmlSchema]
(
    @DataLakeBlobId uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS xml
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @XmlSchema xml
        ,@XmlData xml

    SET @XmlSchema = ( SELECT [XmlData]
                    FROM [landing].[v_tbForm] WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE [DataLakeBlobId] = @DataLakeBlobId
                 )

    --RETURN @XmlSchema.query('</xs:schema>')-- missing matching begin tag
    --RETURN @XmlSchema.query('<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">')-- Expected end tag 'xs:schema'
    RETURN @XmlSchema.query('<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"></xs:schema>')-- nothing in between was returned
END
GO

SELECT [etl].[ufn_GetXmlSchema]('A257667D-C3AA-471C-9F82-91FA35181833')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal, reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following: 
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for a real scenario, here is a good jump start for you. As end result, it creates an XML Schema Collection named ***dbo.StateAndCities***.

> SQL

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections 
                    WHERE name = N'StateAndCities' 
                    AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo'))
DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.StateAndCities;

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
   ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
   , state CHAR(2)
   , city VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (state, city)
VALUES
('FL', 'Miami')
, ('CA', 'Los Angeles')
, ('TX', 'Austin');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @xml XML
    , @XSD XML;

-- Generate XML plus embedded XSD schema
SET @xml = (SELECT NULL,
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl AS [row]
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, TYPE, XMLSCHEMA('MyURI'))
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')
);

-- just to see, XML plus embedded XSD schema
SELECT @xml;

-- retrive just XSD
;WITH xmlnamespaces ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd)
SELECT @xsd = (SELECT @xml.query('/root/xsd:schema'));

-- just to see, XSD schema
SELECT @xsd AS xsd;

-- create schema collection
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.StateAndCities AS @xsd;
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, +1 from my side